# How to store value in variables while looping list of dicts

Tags: python

I want to solve the following problem. I have variable data_json which contain  json data of following structure

```
data_json = 
"api": {"results": 402, 
"fixtures": 
[{"fixture_id": 127807, 
"league_id": 297, 
"round": "Clausura - Semi-finals",  
"statusShort": "FT", 
"elapsed": 90,
"venue": "Estadio Universitario de N)",  
"referee": null, 
"homeTeam": {"team_id": 2279,  
             "team_name": "Tigres UANL",  
             "logo": "url"}, 
"awayTeam": {"team_id": 2282,
             "team_name": "Monterrey",  
             "logo": "url1"},   
"goalsHomeTeam": 1,
"goalsAwayTeam": 0, 
"score": {"halftime": "1-0",
          "fulltime": "1-0", 
          "extratime": null, 
          "penalty": null}},
 ....... another fixture-ids
 }
 }

 the same piece of data in another fixture_id
```

I need to extract values of each key:value pairs and save extracted values to variables. I need the following output

```
var fixture_id = fixture_id[value]
var league_id = league_id[value]
var round = round[value]
var statusshort = statusShort[value]
var elapsed = elapsed[value]
var venue = venue[value]
var referee = referee[value] 
var home_team_id = homeTeam.team_id[value]
var home_team_name = homeTeam.team_name[value]
var home_team_logo = homeTeam.logo[value] 
##the same for awayTeam dictionary
```

I tried looping on my json by following code

```
data_json_looping_on = data_json["api"]["fixtures"]
for id in data_json_looping_on:
    fixture_id = id["fixture_id"]
    league_id = id["league_id"]
    the same logic for each 
    simple key value pairs. But when   
    looping go up on dictionariy i tried
    following loop
    for item in id["homeTeam"]
          home_team_id = item["team_id"]
```

Here is Traceback of above code

```
 ------------------------------------------------      
 TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-8-958a38c41236> in
 <module> 18 venue = item["venue"]
  19 referee = item["referee"] ---> 20 
  for item in id["homeTeam"]: 21
  home_team_id = item["team_id"] 22
  print(home_team_id) TypeError:
  string indices must be integers
  ------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried another method

```
data_json_looping_on = data_json["api"]["fixtures"]
for id in data_json_looping_on:
      fixture_id = id["fixture_id"]
      league_id = id["league_id"]
      #the same for logic for each 
      simple key value pairs. 
      But when go up on 
      home_team_id = id["homeTeam"]["team_id"]
      print(home_team_id)
```

Python arrise the following error

```
 ------------------------------------------------   
     TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-5-1fe42572d5ae> in
     <module> 18 venue = item["venue"]
    19 referee = item["referee"] ---> 20
    home_team_id = id["homeTeam"]
    ["team_id"] 21 print(home_team_id)
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How i can extract values of homeTeam and awayTeam dictionaries? If you have another logic of extracting give me your advise

Here is my real code

```
date_fixt = open("../forecast/endpoints/date_fixtures.txt", "r")
date_fixt_json = json.load(date_fixt)
data_json = date_fixt_json["api"]["fixtures"]
for item in data_json:
       fixture_id = item["fixture_id"]
       league_id = item["league_id"]
       event_date = item["event_date"]
       event_timestamp = item["event_timestamp"]
       firstHalfStart = item["firstHalfStart"]
       secondHalfStart = item["secondHalfStart"]
       round_count = item["round"]
       status = item["status"]
       statusShort = item["statusShort"]
       elapsed = item["elapsed"]
       venue = item["venue"]
       referee = item["referee"]
       for item in id["homeTeam"]:
           home_team_id = item["team_id"]
           print(home_team_id)
```

Comment: why are you looping through home team? home_team_id =  id["homeTeam"]["team_id"]

Comment: When i tried your method python give me the same error "String indices must be integers"

Comment: Why does the traceback show `item["venue"]` instead of `id["venue"]`?

Comment: on your second method can you print (id["homeTeam"]) or do: if isinstance(id["homeTeam"], dict): print(True)

Comment: Sorry dears it was problem of my typing. When i tried to home_team_id =  item["homeTeam"]["team_id"] its worked. Problem arrise because when i started looping with for i used for item in data_json_looping_on but when i tried extract homeTeam values i used id["homeTeam]["team_id]. So sorry for your spended time ) Thank you. If you want you can write right approach for extracting values from dict when looping on list i will flag it like right approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id["homeTeam"]` and `id["awayTeam"]` aren't lists (there are no square brackets around them), they're just single dictionaries. So you don't need to loop over them.

```
date_fixt = open("../forecast/endpoints/date_fixtures.txt", "r")
date_fixt_json = json.load(date_fixt)
data_json = date_fixt_json["api"]["fixtures"]
for item in data_json:
       fixture_id = item["fixture_id"]
       league_id = item["league_id"]
       event_date = item["event_date"]
       event_timestamp = item["event_timestamp"]
       firstHalfStart = item["firstHalfStart"]
       secondHalfStart = item["secondHalfStart"]
       round_count = item["round"]
       status = item["status"]
       statusShort = item["statusShort"]
       elapsed = item["elapsed"]
       venue = item["venue"]
       referee = item["referee"]
       home_team_id = item["homeTeam"]["team_id"]
       print(home_team_id)
       away_team_id = item["awayTeam"]["team_id"]
       print(away_team_id)
```

Comment: When i tried your method python arrise the same error "String indeces must be integers

Comment: Please edit the question and show the full traceback.

Comment: Also, paste the real code, I had to fix a bunch of typos that you made when you were copying by hand.

Comment: I'm guessing you reused the `id` variable, I can't see any other reason.

Comment: Please post the real code, not "the same logic for each". The problem is probably in that part of the code.

Comment: Paste it between lines with triple backticks, then the formatting will be retained.

Comment: I paste my real code. Sorry man i am posting my question from mobile phone and i faced with troubles when pasting code here from stack overflow app

Comment: Can't this wait until you get to a real computer? I've tried using the SO app from a tablet, it's useless for anything other than reading and commenting, IMHO.

Comment: You didn't get rid of the loop like I said.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the whole correct loop.

Comment: Please edit id["homeTeam"]["team_id"] on item["homeTeam"]["team_id"] and i flag it

Comment: Ugh, you keep changing the iteration variable, it's `id` in the earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Your json may be formatted improperly if it is thinking that "homeTeam" is reference to a string and not a dictionary.

try:

```
import json
data_json = json.loads(data_json)
home_team_id = id["homeTeam"]["team_id"]
away_team_id = id["awayTeam"]["team_id"]
```

The second issue may be that it's failing at:

```
fixture_id = id["fixture_id"]
```

because "fixtures" references a list. So you should also try:

```
fixture_id = data_json_looping_on[0]["fixture_id"]
```

Comment: `id` is the current element of the list from `for id in data_json_looping_on:`, it doesn't need an index.

Comment: @Barmar good catch, that was a typo. I meant get rid of the loop and do fixture_id = data_json_looping_on[0]["fixture_id"].

Comment: My fixture_id = id["fixture_id"] get the right value

Comment: for the second method?

Comment: If you get rid of the loop you only process one fixture, not all of them.

Comment: @Barmar i assumed this was just a list of size 1 and 'fixtures' was referencing all of the keys in that one dictionary that make up the list.

Comment: @Naglyj.Spamer it would be helpful if  you could post the full JSON.